# Accessing the properties from a known view his viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, parameters

I have a view that contains an usercontrol with it's own view & viewmodel.

The usercontrol it's views looks like this:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <viewmodel:TimePickerViewModel x:Name="timePickerViewModel"/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

In the viewmodel of the usercontrol I have a property ValidTime:

```
public DateTime? ValidTime
{
    get { return validTime; }
    set
    {
        validTime = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("ValidTime");
    }
}
```

In the view that contains the usercontrol I need to get acces to the property ValidTime:

```
<timepicker:TimePickerView Grid.Row="0" x:Name="timePicker"/>
<Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Plan" Command="{Binding PlanCommand}" CommandParameter="    {Binding ElementName=timePicker, Path=ValidTime}"/>
```

In the viewmodel of the last view I have this:

```
public ICommand PlanCommand
{
    get { return planCommand ?? new RelayCommand<DateTime?>(Plan); }
}

void Plan(DateTime? date)
{
    if(pickedMagnet != null)
            pickedMagnet.StartDatePlanned = date;
}
```

But the DateTime? parameter I receive in the Plan method is always null. But in debug mode I've seen the property ValidTime is assigned a value. I also tried this:

```
<Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Plan" Command="{Binding PlanCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=timePicker.timePickerViewModel, Path=ValidTime}"/>
```

and

```
<Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Plan" Command="{Binding PlanCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=timePicker, Path=timePickerViewModel.ValidTime}"/>
```

but none of these works.

Anyone knows a solution or a best practice for my situation?

Comment: If my explaination is not clear,

I have a main View (Code fragment 3) which contains a usercontrol (timepicker).
This main view has a ViewModel (Code fragment 4).

The timepicker his view is code fragment 1 , while the timepicker it's ViewModel is code fragment 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trying I fixed it this way.

```
CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=timePicker, Path=DataContext.ValidTime}"
```